# Crystal Reports 2011 .Net 4.0 OS Installed on E: gives error when running report

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, crystal-reports-2010

I have one PC whereby the OS has been installed on E: and it has no C: drive.  Onto this I have installed my .Net 4.0 WPF Application which runs fine.

However, when I try to access a crystal report it gives the exception below.   This user is able to access the report from its network location in windows explorer so I assume the act of asking Crystal to copy it locally is causing a problem?

Therefore, can anyone advise where the local copy will be created and/or how I can control this.

Thanks

Code to open report:

```
oReportDocument.Load(oSystemData.ReportPath + StandardReport.RPTFile, CrystalDecisions.[Shared].OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy)
```

Extract of call stack:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException: Invalid report file path.
```

at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.EngineExceptionUtils.DoThrowException(String message, EngineExceptionErrorID id)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ExceptionThrower.ThrowEngineException(String messageID, EngineExceptionErrorID id)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.EnsureLoadReport()
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.get_Subreports()

Answer (score 1):

It makes a local temp copy of the report when you load it. Find out what the temp environment variable is on that system. If it was e:\temp then I suspect you don't have the permissions necessary to write files to that folder.

That said, since it sounds like you are building a Windows WPF application it could be as you suggest and is actually trying an invalid directory like "c:\anything".

To know exactly what is going wrong, I recommend running Process Monitor which you can download here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

It's easy to use, the only annoying thing is the HUGE number of things it observes on your system. To deal with that, right click on the 'cluttering' entries (in the capture window) and choose to filter them out. It allows filters to be on the process (i.e. myWPFapp.exe) or on the TYPE of activity, in this case you want to monitor the file system (obviously).

Once you have it capturing events, and you've filtered it down so it's not rapidly filling up the window, just run your application. You'll see any failed accesses to the harddrive AND the folder it attempted to use.

Good luck.